# Kaffir will go outside of hell ( surah 55 verse

Tags: quran, quran-recitation

surah 55 verse43-44

> This is Hell in which the criminals disbelieve;
> they circulate between it and an intensely scalding water.

The boiling water has to be OUTSIDE of hell for this verse to be true?
Any scholars or exegesis have talked about this issue?